# Error with strcoll (C++)

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I want to sort a vector of strings into order alphabetically. I have coded thus far and I can not resolve the error for strcoll. Also, I am not allowed to use algorithm library. The error can be seen in the bubbub function where I am trying to bubble sort.

I have a few functions that should explain themselves with their names

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

inline void swap(string & a, string & b)
{
    string c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
    return;
}


void input_name(string&);
void sort_names(string&);
void repeat_pro(int&);
void sortArray(string, int);
void print_names(vector<string>& b_list);
void bubbub(vector<string> & b_list);

int main() {

    vector<string> b_list;                                           
    string name;
    int choice;
    int count=0;

    cout << "Welcome to the Business Sorting Program!" << endl;
    do{
        input_name(name);
        b_list.push_back(name);    
        count++; 
        repeat_pro(choice);
        bubbub(b_list);
        cout<<"\n \n Your Businesses are:"<<endl;



        for(int i=0; i < b_list.size() ; i++){
          cout<<b_list[i]<<"\n";
        }




        cout << "\n\n";
    }while(choice == 0);
    cout << "Thanks for using this program"<<endl;


    return 0;
}


void input_name(string &name){
    cout << "Enter in the name of the business: ";
    getline(cin, name);
}

void sort_names(string &name){

}



void repeat_pro(int &choice){
  cout << "Do you want to enter in more names: ";
  string answ;
  cin>>answ;
  cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
  for (int x=0; x<answ.size(); x++){
  answ[x] = tolower(answ[x]);  
}
    if (answ == "yes" || answ == "y"){
      choice = 0;
    }

    else {
      choice = 1;
  }
  }

void bubbub(vector<string> & b_list)
{
    vector<string>::size_type loop = 0;
    bool done = false;
    while ((loop+1 < b_list.size()) && ! done)
    {
         done = true;
         for (vector<string>::size_type count = 0;
              count+1 != b_list.size(); count++)
         {
            string x;
            string z;

            x = b_list[count];
            z= b_list[count+1];

            if ( strcoll (x,z) < 0 )  
            {
               swap( b_list[count], b_list[count+1] );    // swap
               done = false;                    
            }
         }
         loop++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: please post the error and line in which error is there

Comment: needs of type  int strcoll ( const char * str1, const char * str2 ); but you are sending string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by converting my string into a list of chars. then compared them and swapped the vector based on the results. Thanks for the help guys

```
void bubbub(vector<string> & b_list)
{
    vector<string>::size_type loop = 0;
    bool done = false;
    while ((loop+1 < b_list.size()) && ! done)
    {
         done = true;
         for (vector<string>::size_type count = 0;
              count+1 != b_list.size(); count++)
         {
            string x;
            string z;

            char array[50];
            char array2[50];

            x = b_list[count];
            z= b_list[count+1];

            strncpy(array, x.c_str(), sizeof(x));
            strncpy(array2, z.c_str(), sizeof(z));




            if ( strcoll (array,array2) > 0 )  
            {
               swap(b_list[count+1], b_list[count] );    // swap
               done = false;                    
            }
         }
         loop++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can't you just do strcoll(x.c_str(), z.c_str()) right away?

Comment: Why not to use std::sort http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort?

Comment: strncpy(array, x.c_str(), sizeof(x));
            strncpy(array2, z.c_str(), sizeof(z));




            if ( strcoll (array,array2) > 0 )  directly use string compare no need to convert to list of chars

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky, I was instructed not to use it. However, I am aware of the algorithm library and that function

Answer (score 1):

You can use `std::string::compare` instead of strcoll

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

inline void swap(string & a, string & b)
{
    string c = b;
    b = a;
    a = c;
    return;
}


void input_name(string&);
void sort_names(string&);
void repeat_pro(int&);
void sortArray(string, int);
void print_names(vector<string>& b_list);
void bubbub(vector<string> & b_list);

int main() {

    vector<string> b_list;
    string name;
    int choice;
    int count=0;

    cout << "Welcome to the Business Sorting Program!" << endl;
    do{
        input_name(name);
        b_list.push_back(name);
        count++;
        repeat_pro(choice);
        bubbub(b_list);
        cout<<"\n \n Your Businesses are:"<<endl;



        for(int i=0; i < b_list.size() ; i++){
            cout<<b_list[i]<<"\n";
        }




        cout << "\n\n";
    }while(choice == 0);
    cout << "Thanks for using this program"<<endl;


    return 0;
}


void input_name(string &name){
    cout << "Enter in the name of the business: ";
    getline(cin, name);
}

void sort_names(string &name){

}



void repeat_pro(int &choice){
    cout << "Do you want to enter in more names: ";
    string answ;
    cin>>answ;
    cin.ignore(1000,'\n');
    for (int x=0; x<answ.size(); x++){
        answ[x] = tolower(answ[x]);
    }
    if (answ == "yes" || answ == "y"){
        choice = 0;
    }

    else {
        choice = 1;
    }
}

void bubbub(vector<string> & b_list)
{
    vector<string>::size_type loop = 0;
    bool done = false;
    while ((loop+1 < b_list.size()) && ! done)
    {
        done = true;
        for (vector<string>::size_type count = 0;
             count+1 != b_list.size(); count++)
        {
            string x;
            string z;

            x = b_list[count];
            z = b_list[count+1];

            if (z.compare(x) != 0 )
            {
                swap( b_list[count], b_list[count+1] );    // swap
                done = false;
            }
        }
        loop++;
    }
    return;
}
```

Output

```
Welcome to the Business Sorting Program!
Enter in the name of the business: hello
Do you want to enter in more names: yes


 Your Businesses are:
hello


Enter in the name of the business: apple
Do you want to enter in more names: no


 Your Businesses are:
apple
hello


Thanks for using this program
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Comment: `z.compare(x) != 0` is a waste of a 3-way compare, use `z != x` if you really want that (or `z < x` if you were to attempt to get closer to the actual code). However, neither string::compare nor string operators do what `strcoll` does.